# How to use two scroll view in one Activity?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am developing the app that needs the two scrollview which is like follow explained....

1) First scrollview is for the whole activity. i am giving the more content with the three inflator in sigle activity with the different views. so it displays only 2 view therefor i have made the scrollable to view all the content.

2) Another one in the same activity i have the tabs for showing the user activity in one tab i am displaying the list view and another tab i am displaying some kinda things which is more then the screen size thats why i have given the scolling to that activity also.But here in my case both are not working (the list view and the scrollview).

what i can do for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a ViewPager, if I understand ok.

You can check this lib:

[ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Hope this help!

Comment: ok but how to implement it in my project? should i have to add all those classes in my project. I am new in this view pager implementation. And yes i have seen this once and tried it but not able to get the proper method to add this to my project...pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the Recyclerview for the huge content.
[developers link here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview)